# smalltalk fuel output MULTIPLE objects

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

ReferenceStream is not supported anymore and has been deleted in Pharo 2.0.

Fuel which is well written, well documented, well tested and very fast has taken place.

Yet how could we output multiple objects in a time?

here is an example for single object I found yet it is obviously not enough but is as far as I can do:

```
FileStream forceNewFileNamed: 'demo.fuel' do: [:aStream |
    FLSerializer newDefault 
        serialize: objectToSerialize
        on: aStream binary].
```

Comment: Putting all the objects in an Array/OrderedCollection doesn't serve you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment states you would either use a collection object or a dedicated wrapper object. To Fuel it doesn't matter what you do. We use Fuel to serialize a model that consists of two separate graphs and we serialize it more or less like this:

```
FileStream forceNewFileNamed: 'demo.fuel' do: [:aStream |
FLSerializer newDefault 
    serialize:{myModel. myAccessControlList}
    on: aStream binary].
```

Then, after materialization, we put those two objects back into distinct class variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do: `FLSerializer serialize: {anObject. anotherObject. yetAnotherOne} toFileNamed: 'demo.fuel'`